# My a elements have a border around the letters that is not linked

Tags: html, css

For some reason, there is a thin line above and below the letters of the link that will not work right. I've played around with it and looked at similar questions, but nothing has fixed it so far. I'm relatively new to website design, so I apologize if it's sloppy, but here is the code.

```css
.nav ul {
 padding: 0px 18px;
 display: block;
}
.nav a {
 padding: 8px 18px;
 border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
 border-radius: 8px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #000000;
 display: block;
 }
li {
 display: inline-block;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* I didn't want text decoration on any link */
```

```html
<div class="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

Edit:
To clarify, there is an area of the navigation buttons that does not function as a link. For example, if I were to click right above or below 1 (`<li><a href="#">1</a></li>`), it would not take me to the target site. On other threads, the suggested fix was to make the a element display block and the li elements inline-block, however this did not fix it. Also, I forgot to add another portion where I made all a elements text-decoration: none;  I've added it to the code snippet. It should function the same as it would under .nav a, right?

Comment: that is your 2px `border`

Comment: what you really need ,can you more specific?

Comment: thin line above what letters?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the border. Change your css to this:

```
.nav a {
    padding: 8px 18px;
    border: none; /*changed*/
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #000000;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about `text-decoration`.

```
.nav a {
    padding: 8px 18px;
    /*border: 2px solid #eeeeee;*/
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    display: block;
    }
```

Hopefully, this will work for you. Also you will notice that I have commented `border: 2px solid #eeeeee;`. May be you are talking about these lines?

Comment: I'm hoping to keep the border for stylistic purposes, but even when I move it to the li element it does not fix the problem. Also, I neglected to post it, but in a separate portion of the stylesheet I made all a elements have text-decoration: none;   I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just added text-decoration

```css
.nav ul {
 padding: 0px 18px;
 display: block;
}
.nav a {
 padding: 8px 18px;
 border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
 border-radius: 8px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #000000;
 display: block;
    text-decoration:none;   // added this 
 }
li {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```